# Is there a way to send a parameter though a button?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a link witch i would like yo change into a button, the link passes though a parameter and looks as follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View", "Print", new { id = item.SalesContractId })
```

I now want to replace it with a button with this parameter **{ id = item.SalesContractId }**

My button looks as follows:

```
<input type="button" value="Print" id="btnFromIndexPrint" />
```

Could someone show me how i ca go about doing this?

**This is how my page looks so you can see what i'm trying to achive:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Contract.Models.tbSalesContract>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Edit")
    </p>
    <table>
        <tr>            
            <th>
                Company
            </th>
            <th>
                Trading As
            </th> 
            <th>
                Created
            </th>           
            <th>
                Updated
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>                     
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompanyName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TradingAs)
            </td> 
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.C_date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.C_updateDate)
            </td>
            <td>
               @* @Html.ActionLink("View", "Edit", new { id = item.SalesContractId }) *@
                <input type="button" value="View" id="btnFromIndexView" />

            <td>
            @* Add Button to print only if contract state is finalized *@
            @if (item.IsFinal) 
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Print", "Print", new { id = item.SalesContractId })
                <input type="button" value="Print" id="btnFromIndexPrint" />

            }
            </td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to detect the id on the server, or through some client side script?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at the source code that your ActionLink generates, you will see this is just a regular hyperlink. The id parameter is appended to your URL.

So, replacing your hyperlink with a button won't be the same.

In ASP.NET MVC data can be send to your server in several ways. The one that your ActionLink uses is to append your data to the URL. The Routing mechanism will map those to specific properties on your Action method.

Another way to send data is to use a HTML form. A form can have a submit button that will then send the form data to your server.

ASP.NET MVC will check the following sources when searching for possible values for your action method:

1. Previously bound action parameters, when the action is a child
   action
2. Form fields (Request.Form)
3. The property values in the JSON Request body (Request.InputStream), but only when the request is an AJAX request
4. Route data (RouteData.Values)
5. Querystring parameters (Request.QueryString)
6. Posted files (Request.Files)

Comment: So you cant send a parameter though a button?

Comment: If you look at my source code, can you redirect me in a possible way of achieving my goal?

Comment: @Pomster If you are not clear on the difference between a button and a hyperlink, then you really need to do a bit of research on that. With Html.ActionLink, you are not "passing data" to anything. The browser is outputting a hyperlink that will redirect the browser to another page (route). A button is nothing at all like a hyperlink, so your question doesn't make any sense. You could add javascript that would redirect when you clicked the button, but that's not quite the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to use buttons instead of links? If you worried about look and feel then you can apply some CSS and make the link look like button.

Hyperlinks(<a>) are the ones that are created to form connectivity among web pages. I recommend you to use hyperlink instead of a button in your case. Buttons (other than submit) are good if you want to do some client side actions using javascript.

If you still want to use button then you have to rely on some javascript to invoke the controller action.

Comment: I am useing jQuery to invoke the controller actions.